# Does the a-cursor of a-frame detect invisible entities?

Tags: aframe

Right now, the cursor does not seem to identify entities which are invisible. However, I can make visible entities become invisible using the animations.
Any way to do the inverse?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using making objects invisible using the material `opacity` rather than the entire object `visible`.

```
<a-entity material="opacity: 0"></a-entity>
```